# Trying a IF on two conditions on a AWS Security group

Tags: python-3.x

```
sgInRules=[]
        sgInRules = permission['UserIdGroupPairs']

        if permission['ipProtocol'] == '-1' and not sgInRules:
            logging.debug("Permission {} allows all".format(permission))
            return {'Status': 'NON_COMPLIANT', 'Description': 'SG Allows all traffic'}
```

This gives error that key "UserIdGroupPairs" is not found.

Comment: What is `permission`?  Why do you set `sgInRules` to a list and immediately set it again?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming here that **permission** is a dict and you are assigning the value of **UserIdGroupPairs** to **sgInRules** and you have a condition check on whether there is any value for *sgInRules* or not (correct me if i am wrong).

You are getting *key "UserIdGroupPairs" is not found* because **UserIdGroupPairs** is not present in **permission**. You can handle this case by giving default value as empty list if the key is not present.

USE

```
sgInRules = permission.get('UserIdGroupPairs', [])
```

Instead of

```
sgInRules=[]
sgInRules = permission['UserIdGroupPairs']
```

Comment: Thanks. Am checking . I am trying to exclude SG like these

 "IpPermissions": [
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "-1",
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "IpRanges": [],
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": [
                        {
                            "UserId": "178375044839",
                            "GroupId": "sg-02eb874c6acb6ad6d"


One which has  UserIdGroupPairs which are not empty

Comment: @sks please check the spelling of the key

Comment: So, this is an extract of my security group.

 "IpPermissionsEgress": [
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "-1",
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                        }
                    ],
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": [],
                    "Ipv6Ranges": []
                }
            ],
--------

And this condition gives Key error. 

if permission['ipProtocol'] == '-1' and len(permission['UserIdGroupPairs']) == 0: